How can I create a query in PromQL so that it displays all the metrics that contain the xxx label?
How can I create a query in PromQL so that it displays all the metrics that contain the xxx label? I can't find which metric the label belongs to.

To get all metrics that have non-empty* label xxx you might use query
{xxx!=""}

Demo of all metrics containing label cpu here.

* : empty label in Prometheus is the same as non-existent label
